# Groovy unable to resolve java class

Tags: java, ant, groovy

i got a problem by executing groovy from an ant file.

In Eclipse with a launcher, everything works fine but wehn i run the ant file i got the following output:

> Main.groovy: 71: unable to resolve class InitializeDatabase
> [groovyc]  @ line 71, column 40.   [groovyc]          java.lang.Object
> javaClassInstance = new InitializeDatabase()
> [groovyc]
>
> [groovyc] 1 error

InitializeDatabase is a java class in the same package..

```
public class InitializeDatabase {

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Hello Groovy");
    }
}
```

I guess the problem is located at the ant file:

```
<project name="tp" basedir="." default="dbsetup">
    <target name="dbsetup">
        <taskdef name="groovyc" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="../files/lib/default" includes="*.jar" />
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>
        
        <delete dir="bin" />
        <mkdir dir="bin" />
        <groovyc srcdir="src" destdir="bin" />
        
        <java classname="groovy.ui.GroovyMain" dir="../.." fork="true" failonerror="true">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="../files/lib/default" includes="*.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="bin"/>
            </classpath>
            <arg line="build/scripts/src/build/Main.groovy" />
        </java>
    </target>
            
</project>
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Is your java code and groovy code in the same `src` folder?

Comment: Yes, same project, same src folder, same package. The two files are next to each other :-)

Comment: Cool, think I figured out what was missing (see below) hope it helps! :-)

Comment: Sorry, got no time to test it until now.. but looks good.. will try it as soon as possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `javac` task inside your `groovyc` one.  Change:

```
    <groovyc srcdir="src" destdir="bin" />
```

to

```
    <groovyc srcdir="src" destdir="build">
        <javac/>
    </groovyc>
```

And it should work fine.  As it [says here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovyc+Ant+Task):

> Joint compilation means that the Groovy compilation will parse the
>   Groovy source files, create stubs for all of them, invoke the Java
>   compiler to compile the stubs along with Java sources, and then
>   continue compilation in the normal Groovy compiler way. This allows
>   mixing of Java and Groovy files without constraint.

...

> The right way of working is, of course, to use a nested tag and all
>   the attributes and further nested tags as required.

Comment: @MichaelS Glad I could help :-)  Good luck with it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final file which works great.
Thanks to tim_yates!

```
<target name="dbsetup">

        <taskdef name="groovyc" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="../files/lib/default" includes="*.jar" />
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>

        <delete dir="bin" />
        <mkdir dir="bin" />
        <groovyc srcdir="src" destdir="bin">
            <javac source="1.6" target="1.6" debug="on" />
        </groovyc>

        <java classname="groovy.ui.GroovyMain" dir="../.." fork="true" failonerror="true">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="../files/lib/default" includes="*.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="bin"/>
            </classpath>
            <arg line="build/scripts/src/build/access/AccessDbSetup.groovy" />
        </java>
    </target>
```